# MySQL and PHP Sessions Slowing Down Website

Tags: php, mysql, session, web-traffic

and forgive me in advance as I somewhat a newbie. Am going to do my best to explain the situation in a way it could be generally understood. Long story short, as the title suggests. I have a website with lots of traffic, but on a heavy duty dedicated server and by all means, should be running smoothly however the website is generally laggy and takes quite a bit of time to load up.

The server host and I have cornered the problem, but beyond finding the generalized problem actually fixing it is outside of what I pay them for. They extensively looked at why the website is having these major spikes and gave me the following information;

[root@xxx-x-x-xxx ~]#

| Id | User | Host | db | Command | Time | State | Info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | xxx_xxx | localhost:xxxxxx | xxx_xxxx | Sleep | 4 |  |  |
| 20652 | xxx_xxxx | localhost | xxx_xxxx | Execute | 1 | Sending data | SELECT a.*, sum(b.views) as count FROM videos b LEFT JOIN Wo_Users a on a.user_id=b.user_id WHERE |
| 20656 | root | localhost |  | Query | 0 | starting | show processlist |

They then went onto say;

> On deeply investigating on the issue we could see that mysql is
> consuming more CPU usage in the server. As updated in the above
> snippet the database "xxx_xxx" is executing multiple connections even
> if already one session exists. Please modify the code accordingly so
> that the code will check if a session to mysql already exists before
> starting a new one.

I am familiar with my website and it's code and even pretty good on the backend side of things, and I have made a few educated guesses as to what they meant but my guesses did not seem to resolve the website lag/speed issues. So I asked my host for clarification and they responded;

> We checked again and these are the results.

```
> load average: 0.99, 0.90, 0.87
```

> the below logs and server load was increased on that particular time
> which also came normal suddenly.

```
12:10:01 PM runq-sz plist-sz ldavg-1 ldavg-5 ldavg-15 blocked

01:40:01 PM 9 1129 1.17 0.96 0.90 0
01:50:01 PM 14 1129 1.54 1.35 1.14 0
02:00:01 PM 12 1136 0.80 0.98 1.05 0
02:10:01 PM 13 1124 1.23 1.14 1.09 0
02:20:01 PM 12 1138 16.20 7.16 3.29 0
02:30:01 PM 11 1126 1.09 2.33 2.56 0
02:40:01 PM 8 1140 1.37 1.39 1.93 0
Average: 11 1129 1.21 1.10 1.05 0
```

> As per below logs there is an slight variation in CPU usage of your
> domain php processes which may be caused an issue on that time.
>
> You can refer below logs,

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
|User |Domain |CPU%|MEM%|MySQL#|
-----------------------------------------------------------
|xxx|xxx |69.58|0.00|0.0 |
| Top Process | 99.4 | /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/perl /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/awstats.pl -configxxx.xxx -LogFile/etc/apache2/logs/domlogs/xxx.xxx-ssl_log.bkup -update |
| Top Process | 97.0 | php-fpm: pool xxx.xxx |
| Top Process | 47.0 | php-fpm: pool xxx.xxx |

~~~~~~

2022-01-06
Account: xxx Domain: xxx.xxx CPU: 69.58 Mem: 0.00 MySQL: 0.0
%CPU 99.4 - /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/perl /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/awstats.pl -configcxxx.xxx -LogFile/etc/apache2/logs/domlogs/xxx.xxx-ssl_log.bkup -update
%CPU 97.0 - php-fpm: pool xxx.xxx
%CPU 47.0 - php-fpm: pool xxx.xxx
~~~~~~
```

So their response only served to confuse my issue more and as you can see, their is a bit of a language gap as well. I've done my due diligence in researching the topic but am getting nowhere fast and everything I've personally tried have not helped at all either. Any opinions, help or clarification on what I may be able to do would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: What's that perl process at 99.4% ?  Can you examine the cron tab on your machine?

Comment: Hello, upon checking the cron tab this is what I got; https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rUYOHQUIUcbHtPP92lxcFHxK-LBe6RYo/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The perl process showing high CPU usage is the awstats log parser, I think. Nothing to worry about. The info from your provider is very limited but it indicates the issue is in the PHP application layer, not the DB (MySQL: 0.0). The load average basically says that your CPUs (2 x 18C) are asleep. There are so many potential issues that any answers here are just speculation and probably misleading. You really should engage someone to work with you, side by side, and help you understand the current problem.

Comment: The brief spike @ 02:20 - `02:20:01 PM 12 1138 16.20 7.16 3.29 0` should be cause for concern but well within the capabilities of your hardware (2 x 18C(36T)). You need some resource monitoring in place to understand what processes are in play during these spikes.

Comment: Please show the full query, pls the `CREATE TABLEs`.  The solution may be as simple as adding a composite index to some table.  But we need more info to help you.

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND very helpful OS information, includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

In all honesty, the query you're using looks expensive and as the tables grow, you will significantly slow down searches querying that way. I would advise that you modify the query to perform better, stress it and see if you can increase your numbers while lowering delays.

As a tip for hosting, any cloud provider out there will provide you instances you can scale at any time by applying more cores, memory or disk-space. Known as vertical scaling, in time your setup may need to horizontally scale across servers and with that you will want to follow this next tip closely.

Many by default will host MySQL with their HTTP server and this is fine, MySQL default is locked to localhost so access can't be granted outside the machine but this being a safe practice is not an efficient one at all and proves to be very costly.

As the cloud will charge you exponentially more for a higher core-count, most should start out spreading their structure by single cores till this is reasonable so splitting the servers up you don't need a single 8core box, you could get away with maybe a 1-core front, and a 4-core MySQL. Testing would be needed here.

---

Your mention of sessions is not really the case here, but if you feel sessions are overwhelmed make another server and use Redis/MySQL. When you reach 64-cores you can consider sharding or something complicated to horizontally scale the databases. HTTP will scale no problem as long as it's stateless any load-balancer will be your savior.
(An example of this would be, if you're hosting videos, the videos could not be hosted on any of the HTTP servers servicing front-end. They'd be hosted on other servers in the back-end so even if 1 or 20 HTTP servers were online behind balancer they all behave properly and can switch across the servers and still keep a session/etc.)

Any questions ask but this may not be appropriate for SO.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the is very helpful information. I'd have a ton of questions but namely, to clarify, it is the search querying that is more than likely slowing the website speed down overall? And where might you recommend I start modifying this to perform better if I might ask? Also, I'm open to suggestions on where the host/server could be improved. What I am on currently is as follows; 2x Intel® Xeon® Processor E5-2697 v4, 64GB RAM, 4x 480GB SSD, HW RAID storage, Network port 1 Gbps, 2 ipv4 addresses, bandwidth 50 TB, Centos 7, cpanel included and have Kernelcare.

Comment: Yes, your query statement is not optimized and doing a poor search and in turn adds up to seconds when processing, if this is not embarrassing for you to admit, how many users use the site daily? If it's not close to a million users I'd be re-thinking a lot of things with those specs.

Comment: No, not embarrassing at all. But it's true. My website/service grew more popular faster than my development skills did, to make a long story short. But yes, the traffic is almost exactly a million, daily, give or take. Lows of about 500k, highs at a little over a million.

Comment: Okay, so 1 Million requests an hour is enough to delay a single-core server by a few seconds each request... So if you mean to tell me you have all those cores and can't deliver, I am suggesting you fix your queries and re-benchmark your SQL.

Comment: I would HIGHLY recommend, you migrate that MySQL over to a new server and set up the firewall policies to allow only that of your home IP, HTTP IPs and that's that. If you have terminal access and should for major projects like these, check htop for http server and mysql server and narrow in like that! :) I am fully certain though it's your coding and you should be blessed mysql caught your longest query. Also there's the awstats.pl running that is causing blocks in the CPU if this is constant see to removing this completely or changing this drastically.

Comment: @BGPHiJACK I agree with you that the partial SQL statement looks pretty bad but without a detailed load profile and understanding of data structure / scale it could be a [red herring](https://www.google.com/search?q=red+herring). Your recommendation to split DB to separate server, though typically a sensible strategy, is premature given lack of detail in OP's question. Understanding / tackling the performance issue should be the priority, not throwing more tin at it. The generalisations around number of requests per server are only helpful when combined with detailed knowledge of load.

Comment: @nnichols You're way late to the party there bud. Re-read.

Comment: @BGPHiJACK Have just re-read and your last comment starts with `migrate that MySQL over to a new server`. Not an unreasonable recommendation in general but not the answer to OP's current issue. And what is `you should be blessed mysql caught your longest query` supposed to mean? And `awstats.pl running that is causing blocks in the CPU` seems a little strange. Awstats is highly unlikely to overwhelm OP's 36C (72T) box. A trek through the httpd logs for the few minutes around 02:20 will help identify the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

In those speed tests, did you see anything relating to node or sockets failing?

Comment: Yes, actually, I did. Sockets failing.